# Call next activity when video ends

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-videoview

I am new to Android development and I am making an app in which I want that when a video that is playing in a video view in activity_1 ends the activity_2 starts automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that you have a VideoView named videoView(an instance of a VideoView class), then call bellow function on it:

```
VideoView videoView = findViewById(R.id.your_video_view_id);
    videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),YourTragetActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

YourTargetActivity => The activity that you want to start.

---

Documents: 
How to [start another activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity),
and docs of [VideoView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html):

[VideoView's doc image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7HnI.png)

Answer (score 0):

yes for that you can use OnCompletionListener as below:

```
videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // start your next activity from here
    }
});
```

Comment: @Divyanshu Gupta got it?

Comment: Thanx very much it worked for me and i was doing same but by mistake i was writing this code inside the code for next button which was made to call the same activity.

Comment: @Divyanshu Gupta you can contact me if you have any questions.